# "netstat" vs "netstat -a" in Windows

Tags: windows, networking, netstat

I want to know the difference between `netstat` and `netstat -a` in Windows.

I think that this is the difference:

`netstat` will display all of the TCP connections in every **State** except for *LISTENING*.

`netstat -a` will display all of the TCP connections in every **State** (including *LISTENING*), and it will also display the UDP listening ports.

Am I correct?

Comment: you do seem to sum up the differances nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general summary of `netstat` from `netstat /?` says (emphasis mine):

> Displays protocol statistics and **current TCP/IP network connections**.

So when you run `netstat` without any special switches, you only see TCP connections that have been made.

That same output says about the `-a` switch:

> Displays all connections and listening ports.

[The TechNet page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490947.aspx) is even more explicit about that option:

> Displays all active TCP connections and the TCP and UDP ports on which the computer is listening.

Yes, you are correct. The `-a` flag makes `netstat` show the listening ports in addition to existing TCP connections.

Comment: *"when you run netstat without any special switches, you only see TCP connections that have been made"* is a connection that have been made include the *CLOSE_WAIT* **State**?

Comment: I just did an experiment and was able to see `CLOSE_WAIT` connections without `-a`.

Comment: and `FIN_WAIT`/ `FIN_WAIT2`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  From `netstat -?`

> Displays protocal statistics and current TCP/IP network connections
>
> -a    Displays all connections and listening ports.

So I'd say it's safe to infer from the first line that it's only *connections*, adding `-a` gives you connections and listening ports.

Comment: Unfortunately for your answer, the other answer came in two minutes earlier, and had more information.  Researched information showing official documentation is preferred over "I'd say it's safe to infer".

Comment: Hooray for race conditions.